# GetAngleImpl fails on Revolute2 joints

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I gather that GetAngleImpl should be used to get the first angle of a revolute2 joint.

In ODEHinge2Joint.cc that leads to a call to `dJointGetHinge2Angle1()`, which looks like
the right helper function to calculate this angle.

However, in `physics/Joint.hh` GetAngleImpl seems to be wiped out:

```
    `protected: virtual math::Angle GetAngleImpl(int _index) const = 0;`
```

This leads to the following compiler complaint when I try to invoke GetAngleImpl():

```
`joint_state.position[0] = this->front_left_joint->GetAngleImpl( 0 ).Radian();`
```

gets the compiler error message:

```
`/usr/include/gazebo-1.2/gazebo/physics/Joint.hh: In member function ‘void gazebo::ROSModelPlugin::OnUpdate()’:`

`/usr/include/gazebo-1.2/gazebo/physics/Joint.hh:228:38: error: ‘virtual gazebo::math::Angle gazebo::physics::Joint::GetAngleImpl(int) const’ is protected`

/home/cga/drc-cmub/gazebo/models/car/car.cc:94:68: error: within this context
```

`this->front_left_joint` is a revolute2 joint. I can get velocities, but not positions.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/239/getangleimpl-fails-on-revolute2-joints/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can not use [protected functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr129.htm) like that.

To get the angle(s), use [`gazebo::physics::joint::GetAngle(int _index)`](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.2.5/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#ab4897d7b297cd3fd1792dbb9442678ce).

Alternatively you can just get the child link ptr, to get the link pose (e.g.: `GetChild()->GetPose().rot.GetAsEuler().x)`).

---

Originally posted by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) with karma: 86 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on 2013-01-03**:
I do not think ODEHinge2Joint::GetAngleImpl(...) is fully implemented. If you look at the source, it does not report the angles at all (it tries calculating for first axis only, then just returns zero).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-23**:
It's fully implemented in the latest version of gazebo.